# python - how to reassign element in array with for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variable-assignment

I have a numpy array of floats that I want to reassign with a different value using a for loop but PyCharm says the new variable assignment isn't being used.

If I have, say:

```
for i in array:
    i = i * 5
```

It will say that i is an unused variable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has the same effect as `i0 = array[0]; i0 = i0 * 5; i1 = array[1]; i1 = i1 * 5;...` which is not the same as `array[0] = array[0] * 5; array[1] = array[1] * 5;...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign values to array elements. Otherwise you array will remain unchanged. There are a couple of ways.

Using your current attempt as a starting point, you can use `enumerate`. Given an input `array`:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(array):
    array[idx] = val * 5
```

But this doesn't take advantage of NumPy vectorisation. You can simply use:

```
array *= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] = array[i] * 5
```

What you did was creating a temporary variable "i", which exists only on each loop iteration, it is initialized with the value of an element from the list and then it's deleted.

A more pythonic way of doing this would be:

```
array = [i*5 for i in array]
```